# SystemJS core_1.provide is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-mvc-5, systemjs, ts-loader

I try setup ASP.NET MVC 5 (not Core) + Angular 2.0.0 + JSPM + SystemJS + TS Loader.

In my opinion maybe is something bad with TS loader. Any advice?

When I run app I get error:

```
Error: (SystemJS) core_1.provide is not a function
    TypeError: core_1.provide is not a function
        at execute (http://localhost:59711/app/bootstrap.ts!transpiled:26:24)
    Error loading http://localhost:59711/app/bootstrap.ts
```

Here are my configuration files:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    /* target of the compilation (es5) */
    "module": "system",
    /* System.register([dependencies], function) (in JS)*/
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    /* how module gets resolved (needed for Angular 2)*/
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    /* needed for decorators */
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    /* needed for decorators (@Injectable) */
    "noImplicitAny": false
    /* any has to be written explicity*/
  },
  "exclude": [
    /* since compiling these packages could take ages, we want to ignore them*/
    "jspm_packages",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
  /* on default the compiler will create js files */
}
```

**config.js (jspm, configuration files is simplified)**

```
System.config({
  baseURL: "/",
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "babel",
  babelOptions: {
    "optional": [
      "runtime",
      "optimisation.modules.system"
    ]
  },
  typescriptOptions: {
    "tsconfig": true
  },
  paths: {
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
  },

  packages: {
    "app": {
      "main": "bootstrap",
      "format": "system",
      "defaultExtensions": "ts",
      "meta": {
        "*.ts": {
          "loader": "ts"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  map: {
    "@angular/common": "npm:@angular/common@2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "npm:@angular/compiler@2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "npm:@angular/core@2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "npm:@angular/http@2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "npm:@angular/platform-browser@2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "npm:@angular/router@3.0.0",
    "babel": "npm:babel-core@5.8.38",
    "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@5.8.38",
    "core-js": "npm:core-js@1.2.7",
    "reflect-metadata": "npm:reflect-metadata@0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "npm:rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts": "github:frankwallis/plugin-typescript@5.1.2",
    "zone.js": "npm:zone.js@0.6.25",
    "github:frankwallis/plugin-typescript@5.1.2": {
      "typescript": "npm:typescript@2.0.2"
    },
  }
});
```

**index.html**

```
<script src = "../../jspm_packages/npm/reflect-metadata@0.1.8/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src = "../../jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
<script src = "../../config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.config
    ({
        map: {
            "@@angular/common": "npm:@@angular/common@2.0.0",
            "@@angular/compiler": "npm:@@angular/compiler@2.0.0",
            "@@angular/core": "npm:@@angular/core@2.0.0",
            "@@angular/http": "npm:@@angular/http@2.0.0",
            "@@angular/platform-browser": "npm:@@angular/platform-browser@2.0.0",
            "@@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "npm:@@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0",
            "@@angular/router": "npm:@@angular/router@3.0.0",
            "reflect-metadata": "npm:reflect-metadata@0.1.8"
        },
        transpiler: "ts",
        packages:
        {
            "app": {
                "defaultExtension": "ts",
                "meta": {
                    "*.ts": {
                        "loader": "ts"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    console.log("System.Config Init OK");
</script>
```

**bootstrap.ts**

```
import {bootstrap} from "@angular/platform-browser"
import {provide} from "@angular/core"
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "@angular/http"
import {
    APP_BASE_HREF,
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT,
    HashLocationStrategy,
    LocationStrategy} from "@angular/router"
import {AppComponent} from "./components/app.component"


bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    provide(ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT, { useValue: AppComponent }),
    provide(APP_BASE_HREF, { useValue: "/" }),//ng2 potrebuje base tag
    provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy }),//default je PathLocationStragy, treba zmenit kvoli mvc api router

]).catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the change log from version [2.0.0-rc.6](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc6-2016-08-31):

> core: remove deprecated provider/bind API

These forms of providers are no longer accepted:

```
bind(MyClass).toFactory(...)
new Provider(MyClass, toFactory: ...)
```

The only accepted form is now:

```
{provide: MyClass, useFactory: ...}
```

Also final version of Angular2 requires NgModule. Your application is inncorect this way if you use final Angular2 v2.0.0. take a look at [Quick Start Guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) and see how the application should be bootstraped!

Comment: Thank I try Quick Start Guide but sample doesn’t work for me. Error Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined shim.min.js:4492 . It’s very complicated find working sample.

Comment: Try to clone official Angular2 seed project:  https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed - it uses webpack instead of SystemJS (Angular2 has officaly moved form SystemJS to Webpack).

Comment: But in Quick Start Guide is used SystemJS.

Comment: Just read what they write: "Although we use SystemJS for illustrative purposes here, it's only one option for loading modules. Use the module loader that you prefer. For Webpack and Angular, see Webpack: an Introduction. Or, learn more about SystemJS configuration in general here". Basically it is your choice but officialy Angular2 moved into webpack.

Comment: Ok, thank you for information, my problem is that I need work together with asp.net mvc 5, angular2, jspm, systemjs, ts loader. I worked with angular pas month ago everything works with these technologies I know that angular has lot of breaking changes. You have right  I must use ngmodule etc. But still if I use code from quick start it not work for me. I describe my problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39591638/angular2-core-js-shim-min-js4492-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-define.